# How to prioritize jetson nano swap file

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

We have installed Jetpack 4.2.3 on jetson nano. This has created a 2 GB built in zram memory. 
We have additionally added 4 GB swap file using the following 
https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2019/04/14/jetson-nano-use-more-memory/
The system is taking priority to zram. we want to set the newly created swap to take priority over zram.
How to prioritize swap in jetson Nano?
How to change Swap partition priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled zram by removing nvzramconfig.sh from /etc/systemd/ and zram is not invoked when the system boots. Now the swap is working perfect